# How to change the position of a progress bar? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, header, position, progress-bar

At my company we use a survey software/platform which offers some layout templates. The platform allows for CSS modifications and I want to position a progress barcloser to the header image above it. [It looks like this right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPg5M.png)

The CSS codes currently used for these elements are:

**/**Header image*/**

```
div.questionnaire-header {
background: url("/images/uploaded/UMUQJ98W9N1N");
background-size: 100%;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

**/**Progress-bar*/**

```
html .progress-area .progress-bar {
background-color: #666666;
background-image: none;
}
```

I tried using the following:

```
html .progress-area {
  top: 220px;
}
```

However, this creates a problem om mobile; it makes the progress bar appear "over" the content below.

**The HTML code (that i hope is relevant, I'm a beginner) looks like the following. Header:**

```
<DIV class='questionnaire-header'>
</DIV>
```

**And for the progress bar:**

```
<div class="progress-area progress0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-graphical"><div class="progress-completed" style="width: 9%"></div><div class="progress-textual-area"><div class="progress-textual">9%</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use media query to set a different value for top property for mobile devices? Can you make a jsfiddle of your example?

Answer (score 0):

If that CSS creates a problem on mobile then modify that CSS so that it does not apply on mobile.
Use this instead:

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
html .progress-area {
  top: 220px;
}}
```

That code above will use your last provided CSS but only apply it on screens that are at least 1100px in size. Therefore not on mobile.

And if you want a code that will apply only on mobile on screens below 1100px then change the `min-width` value to `max-width`.

Comment: I really appreciate your input! However, this causes two things: (1) when turning the phone horizontally the progress bar shows above the content below it (on the middle of the screen basically) and (2) when also adding the code I used before (outside a media-query) -to make the progress bar closer to the header on the desktop verseion- the progress bar will be shown way down even on the phone. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you have CSS that is affecting your mobile, then simply place that CSS in the code I gave you so that that CSS is only affecting desktop. I wouldn't be able to tell you more unless you have a link or a codepen.